# Can an AWS private IP address server connect to a public IP address server that is in the same VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS implementation that has several server instances within the same VPC.  Some of the server's only use the private IP addresses -- MongoDB server for instance.  Some of the servers have 443 public facing IP addresses.  Can a server that is using its private IP address connect to another servers public IP address?  Also, is the reverse true -- Public IP Server talking to a private IP Server?  Again, all of the servers are in the same VPC.

Comment: i mean.. they all have private ip addresses, as long as it's allowed in the security group and local firewalls they should be able to communicate via either.

Comment: If I communicate to a private IP address does it get NAT'd to the public IP address?  In other words, if I am talking to the application server's private IP address, does the server application see it even though it is using the public facing IP address?

Comment: That i do not know.

Comment: If you use the private IP address it does not get NAT'd to the public IP. Using the private IP is highly recommended because it keeps all network traffic inside the VPC and keeps traffic associated with a security group. When you use a public IP the traffic exits the VPC and then comes back in, which disassociates the traffic from the originating instance's security group. For security and latency purposes you should always try to use the private IP when possible. Once you start using the public IP your inbound traffic is no different from any traffic coming from the Internet.

Comment: No, as long as you use private IP addresses for communicating on both machines it won't be "NAT'd"

Comment: To be clear, public IP addresses get "NAT'd" to the private IP, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a server that is using its private IP address connect to another
>   servers public IP address?

**Yes**.

- Make sure the security group of the server with public IP accepts inbound traffic from the VPC NAT
- Make sure the internet traffic from the private subnet is correctly routed through the VPC NAT

> Also, is the reverse true -- Public IP Server talking to a private IP
>   Server? Again, all of the servers are in the same VPC.

**Yes**.

- Make sure the routing table of the subnet running the public IP server has an entry to route the private server traffic internally
- If you had used VPC creation wizard, the route table entries to route the VPC traffic internally are added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In order for an instance without a public IP address (an Elastic IP address or an automatically assigned public IP address) assigned to it to communicate with public IP addresses, an instance must be inside of a subnet where the route table points the default route to a NAT gateway or NAT instance (generally - you could probably have a route to a specific IP and assign the destination as a NAT gateway or instance). There is no automatic NAT involved. It must be explicit.

A server with a public IP address assigned to it can communicate with a server without a public IP address so long as they're in the same VPC. The traffic will take place entirely within the private IP space. The server with the public IP address can connect to other server using its private address.