# How an EC2 access another EC2 in the same VPC using public IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I find this 
[Can an AWS private IP address server connect to a public IP address server that is in the same VPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907091/can-an-aws-private-ip-address-server-connect-to-a-public-ip-address-server-that)

Both my two EC2s have public IP, and work fine, I have no NAT instance.

How do I 
**Make sure the security group of the server with public IP accepts inbound traffic from the VPC NAT**

Comment: You say you have no NAT instance. Then how can you have a security group that accepts traffic from NAT?

Comment: If both instances are inside a VPC, it seems like an unnecessary workaround to have traffic leave and re-enter the VPC if it can use an internal route. To have any sort of communication with the outside world, your private subnet will need a NAT instance.

Comment: Maybe AWS have default, I'm not clear of that.
I forgot adding the public IP to the inbound rules, now they can communicate. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear about your current configuration, but let's say you have:

- An Amazon VPC with one public subnet
- Two instances both in the public subnet
- They each have Public IP addresses assigned

Yes, the two instances can communicate directly with each other. It is best that they communicate via the **private IP address** -- this way, the traffic remains totally within the VPC.

If they communicate via their public IP addresses, then the traffic goes out of the VPC to the AWS *edge* of the Internet, then back into the VPC. Such traffic is charged at 1c/GB.

All instances within a VPC can communicate directly with each other via their private IP addresses, even if they are in different subnets. However, the **Security Group** will need to be configured to accept the incoming traffic. This can be configured based on the IP address of the source instance, or by reference to a security group that is associated with the source instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot adding the public IP to the inbound rules.